# How to look up date value from same table based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure if this task is of `self join` or not. I am basically trying to lookup the **latest date** for each `State.UnionTerritory` in below dataframe where the `Daily_confirmed` cases for each of them were <= **half of current Date**.

This will help me to get the the doubling time of cases for each State on each date.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df_ind <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/sample_data.csv")

df_ind %>% head()

# output
Date       State.UnionTerritory Daily_confirmed
  <date>     <chr>                          <dbl>
1 2021-12-23 Haryana                           46
2 2021-12-23 Maharashtra                     1179
3 2021-12-23 Delhi                            118
4 2021-12-22 Haryana                           55
5 2021-12-22 Maharashtra                     1201
6 2021-12-22 Delhi                            125
```

For example `Delhi` has `118` Cases on `2021-12-23` and less than or half of this for Delhi is coming as `57` on `2021-12-15` so doubling rate would be  `2021-12-23` - `2021-12-15` = 8 days.

so I should get something like:

[image]

This should be applied for each State in the data & on all dates.

```
df_ind <- df_ind %>%
  mutate(Daily_confirmed_half = as.integer(Daily_confirmed / 2) )
```

I am not sure how exactly I can try this to get proper Dates as the `Doubling_Date` column where `Daily_confirmed` Cases values met the condition of `<= half`.

I can `group summarize` & use `first` to pull the latest dates but not sure what would be the efficient way of bringing the right dates in another column of this data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your desired output. The approach uses a `full_join` together with `filter` to simulate an non-euqal join in dplyr. Then we do some data cleaning and in the last step we need a `left_join` to our original data, since there are quite a couple of days, where we cannot calculate the doubling date, since its not included in the time series.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df_ind %>% 
  group_by(State.UnionTerritory) %>% 
  full_join(., ., by = c("State.UnionTerritory")) %>%
  filter(Date.x > Date.y,
         Daily_confirmed.x > (Daily_confirmed.y * 2)) %>% 
  group_by(Date.x, State.UnionTerritory) %>% 
  filter(Date.y == max(Date.y)) %>% 
  filter(Daily_confirmed.y == max(Daily_confirmed.y)) %>% 
  rename("Date" = Date.x,
         "Daily_confirmed" = Daily_confirmed.x,
         "Doubling_Date" = Date.y) %>% 
  select(- Daily_confirmed.y) %>% 
  mutate(Day_to_double = Date - Doubling_Date) %>% 
  left_join(df_ind,
            .,
            by = c("Date", "State.UnionTerritory", "Daily_confirmed")) %>% 
  arrange(State.UnionTerritory, desc(Date)) 

#> # A tibble: 252 x 5
#>    Date       State.UnionTerritory Daily_confirmed Doubling_Date Day_to_double
#>    <date>     <chr>                          <dbl> <date>        <drtn>       
#>  1 2021-12-23 Delhi                            118 2021-12-15     8 days      
#>  2 2021-12-22 Delhi                            125 2021-12-15     7 days      
#>  3 2021-12-21 Delhi                            102 2021-12-14     7 days      
#>  4 2021-12-20 Delhi                             91 2021-12-14     6 days      
#>  5 2021-12-19 Delhi                            107 2021-12-14     5 days      
#>  6 2021-12-18 Delhi                             86 2021-12-13     5 days      
#>  7 2021-12-17 Delhi                             69 2021-12-13     4 days      
#>  8 2021-12-16 Delhi                             85 2021-12-13     3 days      
#>  9 2021-12-15 Delhi                             57 2021-11-27    18 days      
#> 10 2021-12-14 Delhi                             45 2021-11-15    29 days      
#> # … with 242 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @TimeTeaFan, this is exactly as my desired output but I am actually not sure about the logic that I have used for `doubling` of cases. Though your implementation is bang on. Really appreciate your efforts & help !!